# PowerBI interpreting column types incorrectly

Tags: csv, office365, powerbi

I'm using PowerBI for Office 365 to visualize data captured in CSV files. Often, the program will misinterpret the column types. For example, I'm currently uploading a CSV with a "Total" column that contains positive and negative integers. PowerBI misinterprets this column a character column. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which product you mean exactly - I thought Power BI for Office 365 was discontinued?

Assuming you mean Power BI Desktop, I would use the Edit Queries window.  There is an easy Data Type selector you can use on columns, and lots of more powerful transformations if that doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Perhaps PowerBI for Office 365 was discontinued, but my organization still has access to it. Unfortunately it does not seem possible to change column data types once the dataset has been connected to. So I guess my question is whether there are pitfalls in structuring my data that will lead PowerBI 365 to interpret a column with negative numbers in it as a string column.

Comment: So you mean Power Query in Excel? That uses the same engine & very similar UI to Power BI Desktop, so refer to my 2nd para above.